# Extracting/Writing core 2Gb image from 8Gb SD card

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I burned a 2Gb Linux image to a 8Gb, made some tuning and would now like to archive it for future use.
But, when saving the image to disk, the resulting file is 8Gb large.
How can I specifically extract the 2Gb "core" ?
Of course, I did not expand the initial 2Gb tot he full 8Gb.  When running `df`, the available Linux partition is 2Gb.
I used Win32DiskImager to write the initial image to SD card and then write back to disk after tweaking.

Comment: Please post what commands have you tried already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Linux tools 'dd' may meet  your requirement,the whole command should like:

```
dd if=/dev/mmc_xx of=mmc.img bs=2048 count=1024000
```

Please replace the `mmc_xx` with your sd name. Keep in mind the result of `bs*count` couldn't less the 2G bytes.

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly.   The SD I was trying to clone had two partitions (Raspberry Pi).  For anyone reading this post later on, I cloned the SD with multiple partitions by specifying sda (no numbers) instead of the full mounted partition name (eg sda1, sda3).